# sendinblue not connected to the API

Tags: php, symfony, sendinblue

I use the `sendinblue` API ([Github Link](https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library)) to send sms but I get this error:

> [400] Error connecting to the API (https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/transactionalSMS/sms)

My relevant code:

```
/**
         * @Route("/send", name="cron.send.sms")
         */
        public function sendSms()
        {
            $listSms = $this->smsRespository->findSmsToSend();
            $config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()
                ->setApiKey('api-key', $this->getParameter('SENDINBLUE_API_KEY'));

            $apiInstance = new TransactionalSMSApi(
                null,
                $config
            );
            $sendTransacSms = new SendTransacSms(['sender'=> 'med','recipient'=> '+21665478932','content'=>'bonjour']);

           // print_r($sendTransacSms);
            try {
                dd($apiInstance->sendTransacSms($sendTransacSms));
                $result = $apiInstance->sendTransacSms($sendTransacSms);
                print_r($result);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Exception when calling ContactsApi->createContact: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
            }

        }
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Any help please ... any idea please

Comment: the SENDINBLUE_API_KEY is not correct, did you have an account in sendinblue?

Comment: @thamer yes i have account in sendinblue ... in other functions api is connected but in.my case not authentificated ...

Comment: Have you verified that `$this->getParameter('SENDINBLUE_API_KEY')` correctly returns your api key?

Comment: @Arleigh yes content api key

Comment: Any help please ...